# datepicker range in side textfield in flutter?

Tags: flutter

i have written the code but im getting lot of errors like `The getter 'day' isn't defined for the type 'DateTimeRange'. Try importing the library that defines 'day', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'day'.` same errors for years and months.

please help me to resolve this issue.

I want know the correct code for that.

```
Container(
                          width: 320,
                          child: TextFormField(
                            readOnly: true,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                prefixIcon: IconButton(
                                    onPressed: () async {
                                      DateTimeRange? result =
                                          await showDateRangePicker(
                                        context: context,
                                        firstDate: DateTime(2022, 1,
                                            1), 
                                        lastDate: DateTime(2030, 12,
                                            31), 
                                        currentDate: DateTime.now(),
                                        saveText: 'Done',
                                      );

                                      if (result != null) {
                                        print(
                                            'Date selected: ${result.day}-${result.month}-${result.year}');
                                      }
                                    },
                                    icon:
                                        const Icon(Icons.date_range_outlined)),
                                hintText: "Select date",
                                // suffixIcon: const Icon(Icons.close),
                                fillColor: Colors.black,
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                                )),
                            controller: TextEditingController(
                              text: result != null
                                  ? "${result!.day}-${result!.month}-${result!.year}"
                                  : null,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access result variable inside your TextEditingController, since you define result inside the onPressed method of your iconButton, in order to access it, you have to define a global variable in your StatefulWidget.

You cannot access result.day | result.month | result.year.
This field are accessible only in : result.start.day | result.start.month | result.start.year OR result.end.day | result.end.month | result.end.year

Choosing between end or start it really depends on your scope.

This is a boilerplate example of what you should do :

```
class DatePicker extends StatefulWidget {
  const DatePicker({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<DatePicker> createState() => _DatePickerState();
}

class _DatePickerState extends State<DatePicker> {
  DateTimeRange? dateTimeRange;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 320,
      child: TextFormField(
        readOnly: true,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: IconButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  DateTimeRange? result = await showDateRangePicker(
                    context: context,
                    firstDate: DateTime(2022, 1, 1),
                    lastDate: DateTime(2030, 12, 31),
                    currentDate: DateTime.now(),
                    saveText: 'Done',
                  );

                  setState(() {
                    dateTimeRange = result;
                  });

                  if (result != null) {
                    print(
                        'Date selected: ${result.end.day}-${result.end.month}-${result.end.year}');
                  }
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.date_range_outlined)),
            hintText: "Select date",
            // suffixIcon: const Icon(Icons.close),
            fillColor: Colors.black,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
            )),
        controller: TextEditingController(
          text: dateTimeRange != null
              ? "${dateTimeRange!.end.day}-${dateTimeRange!.end.month}-${dateTimeRange!.end.year}"
              : null,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```